# Getting values of select tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How could I do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function() {
         var sum = 0;

         $("select").each(function() {
           sum += parseInt(this.value);
        });

       alert(sum);
    });
</script>
<?php
     for($i=0;$i<50;$i++) {
         echo "<div>
                  <select>";

         for($x=1;$x<5;$x++) {
             echo "<option value='".$x."'>".$x."</option>";
         }

         echo "</select>
               </div>";
     }
 ?>
 <button>Submit</button>
```

The client is to be able to edit each select tag accordingly. How can I make it so that upon click of the button, the sum for each of the user's selections will be returned?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the value of the selected item to be returned?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: i think you need to say $("select option:selected").val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid. You just need to wrap your javascript with $(function(){...}):

```
$(function(){
  $("button").click(function() {
     var sum = 0;

     $("select").each(function() {
       sum += parseInt(this.value);
    });

   alert(sum);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. http://lancenewman.me/steven_accounts.php and login with instagram

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there. 2 changes:

1. Wrap your button click Javascript between `$(function() {` and `});`:

   ```
   $(function() {
       $("button").click(function() {
           var sum = 0;

           $("select").each(function() {
               sum += parseInt(this.value);
           });

           alert(sum);
       });
   });
   ```

   so that the click handler isn't registered until after the document is ready / the button     actually exists ([explained in detail here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)).
2. You probably also want to change:

   ```
   sum += parseInt(this.value);
   ```

   to

   ```
   sum += parseInt($(this).val());
   ```

   so that jQuery takes care of some cross-browser stuff.

Working demo: [here at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QULCt/)

**Edit**: and, of course, make sure you are including jQuery before you use it!! [How jQuery Works](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)